# Creating master/detail flow with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, master-detail

How can I use the master detail flow inside a tabbed activity?

I have a view pager that has 3 pages.  I'm trying to use the master/detail flow provided by android studio as one of the fragments in the view pager.

Comment: convert activities into fragments? what do you exactly mean by that? 
If you extend your class to activity such as ActionBarActivity, it will be a activity. IF you extend the same to Fragment instead of activity it will behave as fragment.

Comment: Yes thats what I meant
but once I make it implement Fragment its giving me tons of errors and I have no idea how to fix them

Comment: I did not understand exactly what do you mean by implement Fragment, it will be helpful if you post your error and part of code which is giving the error.

Comment: I edited my question
is it clear now ?

Comment: Ok so for you the problem is you need to use the in built master-detail activity as a fragment in your application right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing this:

1. Change the extends from Activity to Fragment.
2. Add the method onCreateView and move everything from onCreate there except `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView():`

   ```
   @Override

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       FragmentActivity faActivity  = (FragmentActivity)    super.getActivity();
       // Replace LinearLayout by the type of the root element of the layout you're trying to load
       LinearLayout        llLayout    = (LinearLayout)    inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, container, false);
       // Of course you will want to faActivity and llLayout in the class and not this method to access them in the rest of
       // the class, just initialize them here
   ```

   // Content of previous onCreate() here
       // ...

   ```
   // Don't use this method, it's handled by inflater.inflate() above :
   // setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

   // The FragmentActivity doesn't contain the layout directly so we must use our instance of     LinearLayout :
   llLayout.findViewById(R.id.someGuiElement);
   // Instead of :
   // findViewById(R.id.someGuiElement);
   return llLayout; // We must return the loaded Layout
   ```

   }
3. Remove method onCreate.
4. Everywhere you access the Activity with this.something or just something replace with `super.getActivity()`. or use the value saved in the onCreateView like shown in 2). Example : `Intent i = getIntent();` become `Intent i = super.getActivity().getIntent()`

Comment: thanks got rid of the errors 
but now its giving me this error at runtime 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: please post the xml code. Since it is a new error/issue it will be help full to you if you post it as a new question. It my answer helped please accept it as an answer and vote it.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do. Did you resolve your issue?